# Which doctype should I use?

Tags: html

Which doctype should I use, if I want to use costumizable divs. With divs animation, images moving, setting div opacity, etc.

I've tried to create a div through javascript, setting its background-color, position, width and height, and adding an onmouseover event to it.

Everything works ok untill I wanted to put a doctype at my html.

I've tried the transitional and strict, both made my div disappear.

So I've inserted the HTML5 type of doctype and my div appeared ok.

Well, I want to make my website with html4.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you website stopped working when you added doctype, it means you have errors in there. Run the validation on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Everything I've read lately seems to say that you should just use a plain doctype so the browsers can use the latest rendering standards.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
```

Comment: I always use this, its the future, get used to coding for HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

There are three Doctype versions for Html 4.01

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

But the best solution is to use HTML 5's one

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding HTML5 `doctype` will cause the browser to read it as a `html5` document. You will have to keep it in mind. There is not that much difference in them. `HTML5` is just a version with better readability. You will have to consider this when you write your code.